# Is there any way that i can make sets from a list using list comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list that contains numeric elements.

e.g. `list1 = [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4]`

I want to sort this according to the frequency of the elements present in the list.

Is there anyway that i can do this in a one liner code?

My approach is to make a list of sets that contain the element along with its frequency.
For e.g. in the above list i would like to obtain the below info:

```
[(4,5), (6,2), (2,2)]
```

Comment: `collections.Counter([4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4]]).items()` ? You do not have sets anywhere in your questions - you have a list of ints and a list of tuples. And no code that does anything with your list.

Comment: Where is your approach? Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: `[(4,5), (6,2), (2,2)]` is not a list of sets, it is a list of tuples.  They can't be sets since `{2,2}` would be invalid (set items are unique).

Answer (score 2):

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is build to do the exact same thing.

```
print(list(Counter([4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4]).items()))
#[(4, 5), (6, 2), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import operator
>>> list1 = [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4]
>>> sorted(Counter(list1).items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[(4, 5), (6, 2), (2, 2)]
```